# Page error is occurring but debug doesn't stop on the line of code that caused the exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

Usually when I debug code an error occurs, visual studio stops on the line of code that caused the error. But for this project it displays the page error and doesn't stop on the line of code. I have checked the settings in Exceptions to throw exception.

Any ideas why the exceptions aren't being shown in visual studio?

Comment: If you wrap the offending line in a try catch, can you put a breakpoint in the catch section? You want to first establish that the debugger can attach after the exception. Also note that it might not be a managed exception, so you might have to tick the other tickboxes in the "Thrown" column under Debug > Exceptions.

Comment: It does attach because I can step through the code.

Comment: Yes; but before the exception or afterwards? If the app is starting up when the exception is thrown, and the app is hosted in IIS, if I remember correctly IIS throws it all away - so the actual exception itself might be what is preventing the debugger from attaching automatically.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Is it an error from your code--or does it look like a configuration/assembly loading error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the build is in `Debug Mode` and not `Release Mode`.

Comment: The pdb files contain info for debugger so he can stop at the specific breakpoint. Do you have these files in the bin folder? How do you debug? F5? Try to put a breakpoint before that line.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put a brake point on the line on you expect the error. While running check if that breakpoint icon changes from solid to just circle with a border. If so make sure you can compile your website  without compile time error

Comment: It does and you can debug as you usually can, but in this project the debugger won't stop on the line of code that caused the error.